# How do I render a <iframe> tag?

Tags: 8

I am using the following code.

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
 $appDir = take_control_app_dir();
 $extpath = take_control_fb_ext_client_path();

 $validationString = take_control_random_string(20);
 $fbpath = take_control_client_path(drupal_get_path('module', 'fb') . '/fb.html?extpath=' . $extpath);
 $form = [
   'example one' => [
     '#markup' => '<iframe src="www.google.com"></iframe>'
   ],
   'take_control' => [
     '#markup' => '<p>iframe</p>',     
   ],
 ];

 return $form;
}
```

The `<iframe>` tag is not rendered.

Is there any way to make it render?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Probably iframe is filtered in `#markup`. Use an `inline_template` instead:

```
  'example one' => [
    '#type' => 'inline_template',
    '#template' => '<iframe src="{{ url }}"></iframe>',
    '#context' => [
      'url' => 'www.google.com',
    ],
  ],
```

Comment: As of Drupal 10.1.x there is now an iframe render element.  https://www.drupal.org/node/3264760

Comment: Am I interpreting this correctly that this new render element does only support `#width` as number in pixels, but no percentages like `'#width' => '100%'` ?

Comment: @Hudri, these are just attributes for the HTML iframe tag, so this is not Drupal-specific. But there is another problem. I couldn't find it in the 10.1.x codebase, this was never submitted. I roll back the answer.